# Using function like OOP method in Haskell

Tags: oop, function, haskell, methods

I'm studying Haskell these days, and got a idea using function like OOP method.

First, define a operator as below:

```
(//) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x // f = f x
```

As you can see, this operator reverses the order of function `f` and argument `x` then applies it. For example, `equals` can be defined as:

```
equals :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
equals = \x -> \y -> x == y

comparison = (1 + 2) // equals 3 -- True
```

Now here is my question. **Is it good approach using Haskell function like OOP method?** That means inversion of function and (first) argument is good or not.

**UPDATE**

Here is the case of backtick(`` ` ``) is not available.

```
data Person = Person { name :: String }
myself = Person "leafriend"
```

then

```
> name myself
"leafriend"
> myself // name
"lefirend"
> myself `name`
ERROR - Syntax error in expression (unexpected end of input)
```

Comment: That's not OOP, that's merely a syntactic oddity. It would be OOP if you'd go and ask the result of `1 + 2` for a method called `equals` and invoke that with the result and `3` as arguments.

Comment: You don't need to define `//`. In Haskell, `f a b` can be written as ``a `f` b``, so you could  just write ``comparison = (1 + 2) `equals` 3``.

Comment: delnan // Yes, you're right. It's not OOP, just syntax in different order. My question is from just curiosity.

Comment: Your // operator is called the pipe-forward operator in F# (where is is written as a |> f).

Comment: This reverse form of application was used in a number of Haskell projects and papers (Wash HTML templating, COM scripting) about a decade ago - though `#` rather than `//` was the preferred operator symbol. This was when Hugs was more popular than GHC. As GHC uses hash as a magic symbol for primitive types and operations, the style feel out of use as the community moved to GHC. I consider this unfortunate as there are notable cases where this style is clearer than normal forward application (once you know the idiom, of course).

Comment: @stephen tetley: We still have one reverse application operator, though! Compare `(#) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b` vs. `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`...

Comment: n.b. `(1 + 2) // equals 3` means `(1 + 2) // (equals 3)` --- it does *not* mean `((1 + 2) // equals) 3`. For `equals`, of course, this does not matter, but for most functions it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is merely a matter of style. (It seems rather cruel to C/Java programmers to use `//` as an operator, though.) I would discourage using this for a few reasons, mainly because:

- It's not idiomatic Haskell, and will confuse any Haskellers trying to read your code
- You shouldn't think of Haskell as you would think of an OOP language

If you're trying to make Haskell look more like your favorite OOP language, you're doing it wrong. Haskell is meant to look like math: kind of lisp-y, with prefix function application, but also with infix functions and operators available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to be familiar with Haskell's convention.

Comment: @leafriend - [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) come highly recommended for new Haskellers.